# can i know how many times a component mounted() in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm just wondering is there any way that I can figure it out how many times a component mounted() in vue?
I've tried counted in mounted() methods like this,

```
data() {
 return {
   mountedCnt: 0
 }
},

mounted() {
 this.mountedCnt += 1
}
```

and for sure it did not work. lol I think maybe I can count by setting data in vuex, but I'd like to do it inside a component, not using vuex or other stuff..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily store some persistent state outside the component. For example (assuming single-file-components)

```html
<template>
  <p>I've been mounted {{ mountedCnt }} times</p>
</template>

<script>
let mountedCount = 0 // persisted in-memory here

export default {
  data: () => ({ mountedCnt: mountedCount }),
  mounted () {
    this.mountedCnt = ++mountedCount // increment "mountedCount"
  }
}
</script>
```

Demo ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-borg-1sosu?file=/src/components/MountedCount.vue

Comment: ahh this one would work easily as well. I will try and do some test. Many thanks! I will study more :)

Comment: hmm never thought of putting something "outside"

Answer (score 2):

What i think of is to keep your component alive with `keep-alive` so you dont lose your data inside of it.

```
<keep-alive>
   <yourComponent></yourComponent>
</keep-alive>
```

Now you can increase your counter with `activated`

```
data() {
 return {
   mountedCnt: 0
 }
},

activated() {
 this.mountedCnt += 1
}
```

You have the disadvantage that your component does not get destroyed and so your data does not get reseted. Well its up to you if this is a disadvantage or not.

Other workaround would be to save it in your localstorage and get it whenever your component gets created with `created()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't even know there's a keep-alive .. thing..? :D haha I think it might work out for many cases with destroy() method! ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside a component if you count the mounted times, the variable will be reset on every remount. You will be unable to retain it.

One way is you can do `console.log()` inside the `mounted`. Or you can use the `Vuex` for such scenarios.